# Submit Button not working as it should

Tags: javascript, html

Hello i'm using this code. i have a problem in this. when i enter input in my input box, it is fine. but when i press enter the page is refreshing for a sec and the input box is auto clearing.

```
    <script>
        function book_suggestion() {
            var book = document.getElementById("book").value;
            var xhr;
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
                xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            var data = "book_name=" + book;
            xhr.open("POST", "book-suggestion.php", true);
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            xhr.send(data);
            xhr.onreadystatechange = display_data;

            function display_data() {
                if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
                    if (xhr.status == 200) {
                        document.getElementById("suggestion").innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
                    } else {
                        alert('There was a problem with the request.');
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Small piece of info; properly wrap all you tag-attributes in quotations :)

Answer (score 1):

The reason your page is reloading is because `<form>` elements catch <kbd>enter</kbd> presses.

Catching an <kbd>enter</kbd> press will submit the form.

Submitting a form without an `action=""` attribute will submit to the same page.

Submitting to a page that doesn't handle the request will simply reload the page, and your form input will be reset to blank.

To fix this, disable submit-on-enter by using javascript to catch a keypress equal to `13` and return false or cancel the event.

---

```
<input type=text id=book onKeyUp="book_suggestion( event )">

... [snip] ...  

function book_suggestion( e ){
    if( e.which == 13 ){
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        return false;
    }

    ... [snip your code] ...
```

That should do the trick.

For what it's worth, people on Stack Overflow don't generally like to modify your code at your request.  This is a simple fix that can be found by Googling for the keywords ("catch keypress", "cancel event", etc.).

Comment: ok thanks for the quick answer :) can you please kindle modify the code ...please....

Comment: used this code 
`<script>
$('book').keydown(function(e) {
  if(e.keyCode == 13) { // enter key was pressed
    // run own code
    return false; // prevent execution of rest of the script + event propagation / event bubbling + prevent default behaviour
  }
});
</script>` it ididn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you, you want to submit yourself form data. You should return `false` within `book_suggestion()` function. And add `onsubmit` to `<form>` element. Make sure it should have **return**. Like that:

```
<form onsubmit="return book_suggestion();">
```